# Invalid item in the dependencies list after importing Android project from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, intellij-idea

After importing generic HelloWorld project generated with Android project wizard in Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA CE I have two errors:

```
invalid item 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK' in dependencies list
invalid item 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES' in dependencies list
```

How to import a project correctly to avoid errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove these dependencies and [configure Android SDK and JSDK yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054197/104891).

Note that Android SDK Platform configuration depends on the JDK configuration, so you need to have both configured.

Don't forget to run `SDK Manager` to download Android platforms you are going to work with.

Comment: Of course you need to know that you will break eclipse's dependencies of the storage format will be .classpath.